# Return a class object from a dll C#

Tags: c#

I have a dll in C# which returns a class object.

DLL code:

**Person.cs:**

```
namespace Extract
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public string address;
        public int age;
        public int salary;
    }
}
```

**Class1.cs**

```
namespace Extract
{
    public class MClass
    {
        public static Person GetPerson()
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.name = "Deepak";
            p.address = "Bangalore";
            p.age = 30;
            p.salary = 20000;
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

I have another program "RunApp" in C# which has the same Person.cs class and tries to get the object from the above dll.

RunApp Code:

**Person.cs:**

```
namespace Extract
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public string address;
        public int age;
        public int salary;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs:**

```
namespace Ex
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person mem = MClass.GetPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

After this, when I compile the "RunApp" code, I get an Error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Extract.Person' to 'Ex.Person' ". I
>   tried changing the namespace of the "RunApp" code from 'Ex' to
>   'Extract', but too the same Error: "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Extract.Person' to 'Extract.Person' ".

I want to send values from the Extract.dll to RunApp program. I want to use this dll at multiple programs.

Can anybody please help how to crack this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but: public fields are not recommended... I strongly suggest you add `{get;set;}` to the end of each of those

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A type is **defined** by its assembly. Two identical copies of `Foo.Bar.SomeClass` in two different assemblies **are different types**, and are not interchangeable - even if they have the same namespace etc.

You should *reference* the library, and re-use the type from there.